# Color background for title row in csvsimple

Tags: tables, color, csv, csvsimple, rowcolor

Assume a simple example centered on the [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple?lang=en) package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

    \begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux
    A,1616,0.394,0.309
    B,6999,0.336,0.999
    C,261,0.378,0.284
    D,171,0.332,0.386
    E,402,0.428,0.241
    \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % COUNT THE ROWS
    \csvreader{input.csv}{}{}%
    \edef\totalrows{\thecsvrow}

    % VISUALIZE TABLE
    \csvreader[tabular=|c|l|c|c|,
    %table head=\hline \rowcolor{gray} \# & foo & bar & baz\\\hline\hline,  % NOT WORKING: \rowcolor not found
    table head=\hline \# & foo & bar & baz\\\hline\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline,
    filter expr={
          test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}
      and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{5}}
    }
    ]{input.csv}{
        Foo=\foo,
        Bar=\bar,
        Baz=\baz,
        Qux=\qux
    }
    {\thecsvrow & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Despite following the [package documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) (see page 12 of the documentation), I find it hard to have the title row have a gray background. Can anyone explain my mistake here and propose a working solution?

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `[table]` option to `xcolor` package.  Also had to add a few `%` to remove stray spaces.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

    \begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux
    A,1616,0.394,0.309
    B,6999,0.336,0.999
    C,261,0.378,0.284
    D,171,0.332,0.386
    E,402,0.428,0.241
    \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % COUNT THE ROWS
    \csvreader{input.csv}{}{}%
    \edef\totalrows{\thecsvrow}%
%
    % VISUALIZE TABLE
    \csvreader[tabular=|c|l|c|c|,
    table head=\hline \rowcolor{gray} \# & foo & bar & baz\\\hline\hline, 
    late after line=\\\hline,
    filter expr={
          test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}
      and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{5}}
    }
    ]{input.csv}{
        Foo=\foo,
        Bar=\bar,
        Baz=\baz,
        Qux=\qux
    }
    {\thecsvrow & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I wish I had spotted that myself.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl I've also found it to be an "unnatural" option...why does `xcolor` have to be *told* to play nice with `tabular`??!!

Comment: May I direct your attention to a more complex issue (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475081/adding-subtracting-to-the-thecsvrow-number-in-csvsimple) using the same example data.