# Adding/subtracting to the /thecsvrow number in csvsimple

Tags: csv, csvsimple, fp, number

Assume a simple example centered on the [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple?lang=en) package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux
    A,1616,0.394,0.309
    B,6999,0.336,0.999
    C,261,0.378,0.284
    D,171,0.332,0.386
    E,402,0.428,0.241
    \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % COUNT THE ROWS
    \csvreader{input.csv}{}{}%
    \edef\totalrows{\thecsvrow}%
%
    % VISUALIZE TABLE
    \csvreader[tabular=|c|l|c|c|,
    table head=\hline \rowcolor{gray} \# & foo & bar & baz\\\hline\hline, 
    late after line=\\\hline,
    filter expr={
          test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}
      and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{5}}
    }
    ]{input.csv}{
        Foo=\foo,
        Bar=\bar,
        Baz=\baz,
        Qux=\qux
    }
%{\FPeval{\result}{\thecsvrow+50} & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}  % NOT WORKING: simply swallows the line numbers
{\thecsvrow & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wish the line number (defined by `\thecsvrow`) to start at 51, not at one. Thus, the rows should display the numbers *51*, *52* and *53* in the first column.

I understand that the proposed (but commented out) code line cannot possibly work, because the desired number would need to be called by invoking `\result` again. Nonetheless, I cannot think of a solution to this problem and hope someone in this forum can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TeX native integer arithmetic to make the change: `\the\numexpr50+\thecsvrow\relax`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux
    A,1616,0.394,0.309
    B,6999,0.336,0.999
    C,261,0.378,0.284
    D,171,0.332,0.386
    E,402,0.428,0.241
    \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % COUNT THE ROWS
    \csvreader{input.csv}{}{}%
    \edef\totalrows{\thecsvrow}%
%
    % VISUALIZE TABLE
    \csvreader[tabular=|c|l|c|c|,
    table head=\hline \rowcolor{gray} \# & foo & bar & baz\\\hline\hline, 
    late after line=\\\hline,
    filter expr={
          test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}
      and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{5}}
    }
    ]{input.csv}{
        Foo=\foo,
        Bar=\bar,
        Baz=\baz,
        Qux=\qux
    }
%{\FPeval{\result}{\thecsvrow+50} & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}  % NOT WORKING: simply swallows the line numbers
{\the\numexpr50+\thecsvrow\relax & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the `fp` approach as originally attempted, you only need to add `\result` to the end of the cell.  That is because `\FPeval{\result}{\thecsvrow+50}` does the calculation and stores it in `\result`, but does not output anything.  However, in that state, the output is floating point, with entries like `51.0000000000000`.  So you also need to `\FPtrunc`ate to get the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

    \begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
    Foo,Bar,Baz,Qux
    A,1616,0.394,0.309
    B,6999,0.336,0.999
    C,261,0.378,0.284
    D,171,0.332,0.386
    E,402,0.428,0.241
    \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % COUNT THE ROWS
    \csvreader{input.csv}{}{}%
    \edef\totalrows{\thecsvrow}%
%
    % VISUALIZE TABLE
    \csvreader[tabular=|c|l|c|c|,
    table head=\hline \rowcolor{gray} \# & foo & bar & baz\\\hline\hline, 
    late after line=\\\hline,
    filter expr={
          test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{1}}
      and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{5}}
    }
    ]{input.csv}{
        Foo=\foo,
        Bar=\bar,
        Baz=\baz,
        Qux=\qux
    }
{\FPeval{\result}{\thecsvrow+50}\FPtrunc\result{\result}{0}\result & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}  % NOT WORKING: simply swallows the line numbers
%{\the\numexpr50+\thecsvrow\relax & \textit{\foo} & \bar & \baz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! You are an amazing source of information. Thanks for the rapid replies.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl Glad to help.